# Extract and match items dealing with multiple data-frames using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which can be created using the code shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'home':[1,np.nan,2,np.nan,3,4],
 'PERSONAL INFORMATION':['Study Number', 'Study ID','Age when interview 
 done', 'Derived using date of birth','Gender','ethnicity],
   'VARIABLE': 
['studyid','dummy','age_interview','dummy','gender','Chinese'],
    'Remarks':[2000000001,20005000001,4265453,0,4135376,2345678]})
```

[image]

```
 df2 = df2 = pd.DataFrame({'level_0': ['studyid','age_interview','gender','dobyear','ethderived','smoke','alcohol'],
 '0':['tmp001', 56,'Female',1950,'Chinese','No', 'Yes']})
```

[image]

**Aim**

1) My objective is to take the values from **'level_0'** column of df2 and look for them in **'VARIABLE'** column of df1 to fetch their **'Remarks'** column value provided it satisfies the the below condition

```
  a) 'Home' column of df1 should contain digits as part of their value( Ex: 1,2,3,4,B1.5,C1.9, D1.2 etc are all valid values for 'Home' column)
```

2) My objective is same as above, but here I would like to take the values from **'0'** column of df2 and look for them in **'PERSONAL INFORMATION'** column of df1 to fetch their **'Remarks'** value provided it satisfies the below condition

```
  a) 'VARIABLE' column of df1 should contain 'dummy' as a value
```

For the above two scenarios, I have written the below code but for some reason I feel that it is quite lengthy/inefficient. There should be some easy way to do this.

**Scenario - 1**

```
qconc_id = []
missed_items=[]
col_list=[]
for i in df7.index:
   ques = df7['level_0'][i]
   col_list.append(ques)
   try:
      qindex = int(df[df['VARIABLE']==ques].index[0]), 
                    df.columns.get_loc('VARIABLE')
    pos_qindex = qindex[0]
    ques_value = df['home '][pos_qindex]
    result = re.match(r"[A-Z]?[\d]?[\.]?[\d]+", ques_value)
    while result is None:
        pos_qindex = pos_qindex-1
        ques_value = df['home '][pos_qindex]
        result = re.match(r"[A-Z]?[\d]?[\.]?[\d]+", ques_value)
    qconc_id.append(df['Remarks'][pos_qindex])
    except:
        missed_items.append(ans)
```

**Scenario - 2**

```
aconc_id = []
missed_items=[]
ans_list=[]
for i in df7.index:
    ans = df7[0][i]
    print("ans is ",ans)
    ans_list.append(ans)
    idx=0
    try:
        aindex = df[df['PERSONAL 
         INFORMATION'].str.contains(ans,case=False,regex=False)].index
         print(aindex)
         pos_aindex = aindex[idx]
         while (df['VARIABLE'][pos_aindex] !='dummy') and 
        (df['PERSONAL INFORMATION'].str.contains('Yes|No',regex=True) 
        [pos_aindex])==False):
             pos_aindex = aindex[idx+1]
         print("The value is ",df['Remarks'][pos_aindex])
         aconc_id.append(df['Remarks'][pos_aindex])
    except:
          print("Goes to Exception")
          aconc_id.append('0')
          missed_items.append(ans)
```

Please note these two things

a) I have used while loop because the values might be repeating. For example, we might have a matching value as 'No' but the df1['VARIABLE'] may not be dummy. So I increase the id values in both scenarios to find whether the next occurrence of 'No' has 'Dummy' value for VARIABLE column. The same applies for scenario 1 as well

b) How can I handle scenarios like "No" when finds match in "Notes", "Nocase". As you can see from my code that I am using regex but it still am encountering error here.

As you can see, I am making some modifications to the code and writing it twice. How can I make it elegant and efficient? I am sure there must be very easy and simple way to do this.

Any suggestions/ideas on alternative approach w.r.t to changing the data format of source data or using merge/join approach is also welcome.

I expect the output, the 'Remarks' value to be stored in the list. Please find the screenshot of what I have done

[image]

Comment: IMO, if you can make the question a little shorter, it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid as much as possible explicit loops in pandas, because they will not be vectorized (optimized in pandas and numpy wording). Here you could merge your dataframes:

1. Scenario 1:

   ```
   # extract values where df2.level_0 == df1.VARIABLE
   tmp = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(df2.level_0), df1.loc[:,['home', 'VARIABLE', 'Remarks']],
        left_on = ['level_0'], right_on=['VARIABLE'])
   # drop lines where home would not contain a digit
   tmp.drop(tmp.loc[~tmp.home.astype(np.str_).str.contains(r'\d')].index,
        inplace=True)
   # extract the Remarks column into a list
   lst = tmp.Remarks.tolist()
   ```

   With your example data I get `[2000000001, 4265453, 4135376]`
2. Scenario 2:

   ```
   tmp = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(df2['0']), df1.loc[:,['PERSONAL INFORMATION',
                             'VARIABLE', 'Remarks']],
        left_on = ['0'], right_on=['PERSONAL INFORMATION'])
   tmp.drop(tmp.loc[~tmp['VARIABLE'] == 'dummy'].index, inplace=True)
   lst.extend(tmp.Remarks.tolist())
   ```

   With your example data I get no additional values because from the first step, `tmp` is an empty dataframe.

Comment: Can you tell me what does this line do?  df1.loc[:,['home', 'VARIABLE', 'Remarks']]. When I run this line isolated, it returns Nan for all values under 'Home' column. For example, what's the diff between df1['home'] and df1.loc[:,['home']]?

Comment: In addition, is there any difference between using astype(str) and astype(np.str_)?

Comment: Actually, instead of having two scenarios, I would like to have it as one scenario. Hence I felt my code is inefficient and lengthy as I kind of repeat more or less similar lines of code. Can your code be modified like that? I am trying as well.. Thanks for your response.. Studyid, personal information and level_0 is all related.